# Installing python packages in a different location than default by pip or conda

Tags: python, pip, package, conda

How do you use a Python package such as `Tensorflow` or `Keras` if you cannot install the package on the drive on which `pip` always saves the packages?

I'm a student at a university and we don't have permission to write to the `C` drive, which is where pip works out of (I get a you don't have write permission error when installing packages through pip or conda`).

I do have memory space available on my user drive, which is separate from the `C` drive (where the OS is installed).

So, is there any way I can use these Python libraries without it being installed?

Maybe I can install the package on my user drive and ask the compiler to access it from there? I'm just guessing here, I have no knowledge of how this works.

Comment: You can use a virtualenv.

Comment: but wont virtual environment add extra latency when training the model?, especially if its a deep NN

Comment: @amithmurakonda I think you might mistake virtual evnironments with virtual machines

Answer (score 0):

1. install conda
2. create new environment (conda create --name foobar python=3.x list of packages
3. use anaconda to activate foobar (activate foobar)
4. check pip location by typing in cmd 'where pip' to be sure you use pip from withing the python from withing the foobar environment and not the default python installed in your system outside of your conda environment

and next use the pip from above location to install requested library into your environment.

ps. you may want to consider to install Cygwin on your Windows machine to get use to work with Linux environment.

Comment: Since OP is using windows (talking about a `C` drive), you might consider adding the step "open anaconda promtpt" and changing `source activate` to just `activate`